# Как сменить на нужный язык в терминале?

Tags: linux

Как сменить на нужный язык в терминале в Linux? Есть 5 языков, и чтобы не нажимать каждый раз связку клавиш, ищу альт. вариант. Т.е как поменять раскладку на нужную из пяти доступных языков через терминал. Есть ли он ?

Comment: что значит "сменить на нужный язык"? поясни весь вопрос подробней, хотя бы на уровне «как сейчас» — «как хочу».

Comment: Если это переключение раскладки, то настройте себе CapsLock и радуйтесь

Comment: да, вопросу не хватает детализации. без неё ответ придётся делать очень длинным, чтобы включить все возможные вариации. так что нажмите, пожалуйста, [edit], и уточните текст вопроса.